Angular Listview and Gridview
I would like to implement Listview and Gridview using Angular.  Their features must include the following

paging

sorting

filtering

searching


The Gridview should also support Nested Gridview.
What's current commonly and popular used ? Thanks.

I suggest to you using Ag-Grid for advanced grid features in Angular. Ag-Grid simplifies implementation of filtering, sorting, paging, and searching, along with supporting nested grids.
Those examples include Angular code to demonstrate what you need:
example1
example2
I also encourage you to explore ag-grid angular documentation for more features and detailed guidance

Thanks for your comment ! Can you recommend any Listview/Gridview controls are free of charge to used ?

Unfortunately, it's common that libraries providing advanced features often come with paid options. From what I've seen, Ignite UI for Angular is an example of a UI library that offers advanced grid components. On the other hand, there are also free options for grid components in Angular, such as angular material table, ngx-datatable, and primeng datatable

Regarding Ag-Grid, I want to highlight that Ag-Grid offers Community Edition, which is free for commercial use.

Thanks a lot for all your valuable comments!
